# How can i continue rect 360 to 0?

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to like this [heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6jeV.jpg) but I can't continue like this image. How can i continue like this?

My code is =>

```
let rectBox = {
        groupPadding: false,
        pointPadding: 0,
        borderRadius: 0,
        showInLegend: false,
        borderColor: '#ff0099',
        borderWidth: 2,
        color: 'none',
        nullColor: '#fff',
        type: 'columnrange',
        pointWidth: this.selectedItemWidth,
        data: [{
            x: distance,
            low: lowerValue,
            high: higherValue,
            color: 'none'
        }]}
```

Comment: Could you reproduce your case on some online editor which I could work on?

Comment: Hi @SebastianWędzel, Sorry for late answer I figure this problem out. I used 2 additional rect and calculate position.